# Echo specific array data from multidimensional ray PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

```
{
  sources:
  {
    object: "list"
    total_count: 1
    has_more: false

    data:
    [
      {
         id: card_15ebjVE0mF1nHaPGVYigZadr
         name: "John Doe"
       }
    ]
 },
 default_source: "card_15ebjVE0mF1nHaPGVYigZadr"
}
```

I am trying to echo out the name "John Doe" and nothing else. I can echo $customer[sources] array just fine, but when I attempt to echo $customer[sources]->data->name it just echos the word Array

Comment: Try: `$customer[sources]->data[0]->name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$customer[sources]->data` is an array of objects. You can access a specific object via its key.

if there is only ever one, then `$customer['sources']->data[0]->{property}` will work for you.

If there are more than one, then you will need to iterate the array:

```
foreach($customer['sources']->data as $item){
    echo $item->name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, haha :D

```
$string = ...data from your file...
$a = exlode('name: "',$string);
$b = explode('"',$a[1]);
$yourName = $b[0];
```

;-)